# How to properly reference a particular state in a changing array value?

Tags: ruby, variables, reference

In Ruby, how can the state of a referenced object be saved without it being updated along with the original object? As a rough example...

```
collection_of_strings = []
a = "String"
collection_of_strings << a
a.some_additive_method              #=> "New String"
collection_of_strings << a 
a.some_other_additive_method        #=> "Another New String"
collection_of_strings << a

collection_of_strings.each do |s|
  puts s
end

#=> ["Another New String", "Another New String", "Another New String"]
```

Instead, I'm wondering how can the state be preserved each time so that the final result becomes

```
#=> ["String", "New String", "Another New String"]
```

I know this is an awfully generic question, so if there are any books are resources that address this, that'd be great too! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this without changing the way you use your objects. Ruby references objects using pointers which are passed by value. So in your example the VM does the following

1. Allocate an object for `"String"`, store a pointer to it in the variable `a`
2. Copy the pointer from `a` and add it to the end of `collection_of_strings`
3. Repeat previous two more times

So at the end you get an array containing three identical pointers all pointing at the same object. If `some_additive_method` modifies that object in place, you will see the change reflected across every pointer to that object: `a` and all the elements of `collection_of_strings`. You have to change your code so that you end up with references to different objects e.g.

```
collection_of_strings = []
a = "String"
collection_of_strings << a.dup
a.some_additive_method
collection_of_strings << a.dup
a.some_other_additive_method
collection_of_strings << a.dup
```

Comment: Thank you very much Max! I never thought of duplicating the variable to essentially create a new object. That's brilliant!

Comment: You're welcome. Though to be clear, this is duplicating the _object pointed to_ by the variable. Not the variable itself. Ruby doesn't have variable references like some other programming languages.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying! So by calling dup, it's essentially forcing a new pointer object to be made each time, thereby giving it "room" to store unique string values? *mind blown*

Comment: It doesn't just make a new pointer, it duplicates the string object and returns a pointer to that new object. It's not really about having "room" either. Anything that "stores" an object (a variable, array, hash, instance variable, constant, etc.) just stores a pointer to that object without caring what object is being pointed to.

Comment: Your answers got me reading about pointers and now what you're saying now makes perfect sense! Thank you for teaching me something Max, much appreciated!